# Merge files with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataset

I have over two thousands csv files in a folder as follows:

`University_2010_USA.csv, University_2011_USA.csv, Education_2012_USA.csv, Education_2012_Mexico.csv, Education_2012_Argentina.csv,`

and

`Results_2010_USA.csv, Results_2011_USA.csv, Results_2012_USA.csv, Results_2012_Mexico.csv, Results_2012_Argentina.csv,`

I would like to match the first csv files in the list with the second ones based on "year" (2012, etc.) and "country" (Mexico, etc.) in the file name. Is there a way to do so quickly? Both the csv files have the same column names and I'm looking at the following code:

```
df0 = pd.read_csv('University_2010_USA.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('Results_2010_USA.csv')
new_df = pd.merge(df0, df1, on=['year','country','region','sociodemographics'])
```

So basically, I'd need help to write a for-loop that iterates over the datasets... Thanks!

Comment: mabye get all names with `University` and replace word `University` with `Results` and you will have matching filenames. OR replace first word with `*` to run lines like `glob.glob("*_2012_USA.csv")` to match all files with the same year and country.

Comment: Why is `Education_2012_Mexico.csv` appearing on both list? Is there a rule to which file would go to which dataframe (df0 or df1)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

university = []
results = []
for file in Path('/path/to/data/folder').glob('*.csv'):
    # Determine the properties from the file's name
    file_type, year, country = file.stem.split('_')
    if file_type not in ['University', 'Result']:
        continue

    # Make the data frame, with 2 extra columns using properties
    # we extracted from the file's name
    tmp = pd.read_csv(file).assign(
        year=int(year),
        country=country
    )
    if file_type == 'University':
        university.append(tmp)
    else:
        results.append(tmp)

df = pd.merge(
    pd.concat(university),
    pd.concat(results),
    on=['year','country','region','sociodemographics']
)
```

Comment: `tmp = pd.read_csv(tmp).(#more code)` ... seems like maybe you meant `tmp = pd.read_csv(file).(#more code)`

Comment: Granted, more details are needed from OP; I understand that the string at the start of the filename is irrelevant (where your code would then erroneously discard any files that started with a string not equal to `University` or `Results` -- in OP, there are also example files beginning `Education` that (as I understand) the OP wants to read as well).

Comment: I understand the distinction between which file goes to `df_a` vs which goes to `df_b` is what /folder/ the file is in; files in folder A go in `df_a` and files in folder B go in `df_b` (though OP hasn't clearly defined desired output data structure -- two DataFrames? Two lists of DataFrames? Dicts of DataFrames? Something else?)

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp maybe I shouldn't code after a few beers. Anyhow, the question is not clear as I don't know which file (`Univeristy*`, `Education*` and `Results*`) go to which list